# Installing python bindings for Selenium 2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone explain (detailed directions) how I should go about installing python bindings for Selenium 2 aka Webdriver? I have read the instruction I found at:http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings but they are a little high level. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try one of the following command :

```
$sudo pip install selenium
```

or

```
$sudo easy_install selenium
```

does it work? what's your OS ?